# I have a project about firebase authentication, but I get an error while registering

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

```js
app.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password, confirmPassword } = req.body;
    try {
        const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        const user = userCredential.user;
        const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, 'userdata'), {
            uid: user.uid,
            name: name,
            email: email,
            premium: 0
        });
        console.log('Added user document with ID: ', docRef.id);
        res.redirect("/login");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Signup error:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Signup error" });
    }
});
```

I'm getting Signup error:

> FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation).
> at createErrorInternal (C:\Users\xexez\Desktop\savoryscripter-premium\node_modules@firebase\auth\dist\node\totp-d9065ba0.js:536:55)
> at _fail (C:\Users\xexez\Desktop\savoryscripter-premium\node_modules@firebase\auth\dist\node\totp-d9065ba0.js:507:31)
> at C:\Users\xexez\Desktop\savoryscripter-premium\node_modules@firebase\auth\dist\node\totp-d9065ba0.js:1002:29
> at step (C:\Users\xexez\Desktop\savoryscripter-premium\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:195:27)
> at Object.next (C:\Users\xexez\Desktop\savoryscripter-premium\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:176:57)
>
> at fulfilled (C:\Users\xexez\Desktop\savoryscripter-premium\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:166:62)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections(node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {   code:
> 'auth/admin-restricted-operation',   customData: {} }

error in my code and I couldn't solve it no matter what I did. There is no problem with the login process, I just get an error while registering.

I have a code like this

```html
<form class="login100-form validate-form" action="/signup" method="POST">
    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
        <input class="input100" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Adınız">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
        <span class="symbol-input100">
            <i class="fa  fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
        <input class="input100" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
        <span class="symbol-input100">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </div>

    <!-- Update Signup Form (HTML) -->
    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Password is required">
        <input class="input100" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Şifre">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
        <span class="symbol-input100">
            <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Password is required">
        <input class="input100" type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword"
            placeholder="Şifre Tekrar">

        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
        <span class="symbol-input100">
            <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
        <div id="passwordMismatch" style="color: red;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="passwordLengthError" style="color: red;"></div>
    <div id="emailExistsError" style="color: red;"></div>


    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
        <button class="login100-form-btn" type="submit">Kayıt Ol</button>

    </div>



    <div class="text-center p-t-136">
        <a class="txt2" href="login">
            Giriş Yap
            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

and when you write your username, e-mail, password and password repeat, it should be sent to /login, but it doesn't work.